# Jenkins pipeline, mvn not reconegize as an internal command or external, an operable program or a batch file

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I'm doing a pipeline, when doing a mvn clean install command in my project, this error mvn not reconegize as an internal command or external, an operable program or a batch file.
My project is a Maven java project, my operating system is windows 10

JenkinsFile

```
  pipeline {
  agent any

 stages {
 stage('Unit tests') {
   steps {
   // Run the maven build
          //  if (isUnix()) {
              //  sh "'${mvnHome}/bin/mvn' clean test -Dtest=TestRunner"
           // } else {
                bat 'mvn clean test'
           // }
  }   
}

stage("build & SonarQube analysis"){
 agent any
     steps {
 withSonarQubeEnv('My SonarQube Server') {
            bat 'C:/Users/ANTONIO/Documents/sonar-scanner-4.2.0.1873-windows/bin/sonar-scanner'
         }
      }
   }

stage("Quality Gate") {
        steps {
          timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') {
              error "Pipeline aborted due to quality gate failure: ${qg.status}"
              waitForQualityGate abortPipeline: true

        }
     }
 }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your agent does not have maven installed on it. Also, check if maven is installed on the path mentioned here.